# Проблема с составление запроса SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Возникла проблема с формированием запроса (Отобразить публикации, у которых более 2 авторов и все авторы мужчин

```
Select Название_публикации, count(АвторПубликаций.id_автора) as Количество_Авторов
from Публикации, АвторПубликаций, Авторы
where (Публикации.Код_публикации=АвторПубликаций.Код_пуб ликации and Авторы.id_автора = АвторПубликаций.id_автора )
group by Название_публикации,Пол
having count(АвторПубликаций.id_автора)>=2 and Пол='М';
```

В итоге выводит не совсем правильно. Отобразить публикации, у которых более 2 авторов -> данную часть выводит правильно , а вторую "и все авторы мужчин" нет (выводит кол-во авторов мужского пола у данной публикации)

Как сделать запрос что бы выводились публикации только там где ВСЕ авторы мужчины ?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Название_публикации, count(АвторПубликаций.id_автора) as Количество_Авторов
from Публикации, АвторПубликаций, Авторы
where (Публикации.Код_публикации=АвторПубликаций.Код_публикации and Авторы.id_автора = АвторПубликаций.id_автора ) and Название_публикации in (select Название_публикации from Публикации, АвторПубликаций, Авторы where (Публикации.Код_публикации=АвторПубликаций.Код_публикации and Авторы.id_автора = АвторПубликаций.id_автора ) group by Название_публикации having count(distinct Пол)=1)
and Пол ='М'
group by Название_публикации
having count(АвторПубликаций.id_автора)>=2
```

Вот готовое решение(возможно не самое лучшее(ужасное)).

Comment: ничего ужасного, перемножения можно на джойны заменить, чтобы более прозрачно было, но для оптимизатора это без разницы. запрос как запрос.

Comment: А вы не могли бы мне помочь с одним запросом "Найти выпуски по каждому журналу с максимальным и минимальным количеством страниц"

Comment: Ан нет, вижу проблемы с текущим запросом, просто он не весь виден был :) подзапрос там явно лишний. Допишите в вопрос чуть более развёрнуто, помогу.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1476969/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b6%d1%83%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%83-%d1%81-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8