# Найти выпуски по каждому журналу с максимальным и минимальным количеством страниц

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть несколько журналов, в каждом из них есть определенное кол-во выпусков этих журналов и в каждом выпуске находятся несколько публикаций. У каждой публикации есть кол-во страниц.
Необходимо найти для каждого журнала выпуск с максимальным/минимальным кол-вом страниц.
Таблица имеет вид

```
CREATE table Журналы( 
id_журнала INT identity  PRIMARY KEY ,
Название VarChar(100) NOT NULL,
Издатель VArChar(100) NOT NULL
);
CREATE table Выпуски_журналов( 
Индентификатор_выпуска INT identity PRIMARY KEY,
Номер_выпуска INT NOT NULL ,
Год INT 
); 
CREATE table Публикации( 
Код_публикации INT identity PRIMARY KEY,
Индентификатор_выпуска int references Выпуски_журналов,
Название_публикации VArChar(100) NOT NULL ,
Страницы INT check (Страницы>=1 and Страницы<=15) 
);
```

Comment: mysql <> sql-server, Пожалуйста, исправьте свои теги

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Ожидаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.

Comment: джойним всем в кучу, по ранги по журналу и выпуску в обе стороны, берем первые

Comment: да не надо там ничего джойнить, для данной задачи одной таблички хватит

Comment: У вас нет связи в отношениях "Журналы" и "Выпуски_журналов" - непонятно как их соотнести, без этого и запрос построить не получится

Answer (score 0):

Я возможно заморочился, просто настроение такое... Короче вот:

```
USE tempdb

GO

IF OBJECT_ID('Публикации') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE Публикации
IF OBJECT_ID('Выпуски_журналов') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE Выпуски_журналов
IF OBJECT_ID('Журналы') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE Журналы

CREATE table Журналы( 
id_журнала INT identity  PRIMARY KEY ,
Название VarChar(100) NOT NULL,
Издатель VArChar(100) NOT NULL
);
CREATE table Выпуски_журналов( 
Индентификатор_выпуска INT identity PRIMARY KEY,
Номер_выпуска INT references Журналы,
Год INT 
); 
CREATE table Публикации( 
Код_публикации INT identity PRIMARY KEY,
Индентификатор_выпуска int references Выпуски_журналов,
Название_публикации VArChar(100) NOT NULL ,
Страницы INT check (Страницы>=1 and Страницы<=15) 
);

GO

DECLARE
  @Cnt INT = 3;

;WITH CTE AS(SELECT 1 N UNION ALL SELECT N+1 FROM CTE WHERE N<@Cnt)
INSERT Журналы SELECT NEWID(), NEWID() FROM CTE

;WITH CTE AS(SELECT 1 N UNION ALL SELECT N+1 FROM CTE WHERE N<@Cnt)
INSERT Выпуски_журналов SELECT id_журнала, 
1000 + ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID()AS VARBINARY) AS INT))%2000 --год, ну всякое бывает))
FROM Журналы, CTE

;WITH CTE AS(SELECT 1 N UNION ALL SELECT N+1 FROM CTE WHERE N<@Cnt)
INSERT Публикации
SELECT Индентификатор_выпуска, NEWID(), 1 + ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID()AS VARBINARY) AS INT))%15
FROM CTE, Выпуски_журналов

--Собственно сам запрос

;
SELECT *
FROM(
  SELECT Z.id_журнала, Z.Издатель, Z.Название
    ,Страницы
    ,MIN(Страницы)OVER(PARTITION BY Z.id_журнала) AS Min_Cnt
    ,MAX(Страницы)OVER(PARTITION BY Z.id_журнала) AS Max_Cnt
  FROM Выпуски_журналов AS V
    JOIN Публикации AS P ON V.Индентификатор_выпуска = P.Индентификатор_выпуска
    JOIN Журналы AS Z ON Z.id_журнала = V.Номер_выпуска
  )T
WHERE страницы IN (Min_Cnt, Max_Cnt)


--To receiver:
SELECT * FROM Журналы
SELECT * FROM Выпуски_журналов
SELECT * FROM Публикации
```

Думаю, разберётесь..